MassTransit - How do I setup a job consumer to process 1 job at a time?
I am publishing a message to start a job. I have a consumer setup and from what I can tell, I have configured it to process 1 job at a time. All of the other jobs should remain in the queue until this one finishes. The problem is once 1 job begins, and I publish more jobs, they get sent to the job_error queue with the message of The JobSubmitted event is not handled during the Started state for the JobStateMachine state machine.
I have tried a number of combinations to get this to work, but I just can't seem to figure it out. Am I setting this up improperly?
Program configuration
 builder.Services.AddMassTransit(x =>
 {
     x.AddDelayedMessageScheduler();
     x.SetEndpointNameFormatter(new SnakeCaseEndpointNameFormatter(includeNamespace: true));

     x.AddConsumer<OnArchiveTimedRequestsToCheaperStorage, OnArchiveTimedRequestsToCheaperStorageDefinition>();

     //x.AddConsumers(typeof(Program).Assembly);

     x.SetJobConsumerOptions();
     x.SetInMemorySagaRepositoryProvider();
     x.AddJobSagaStateMachines();

     x.UsingAzureServiceBus((context, cfg) =>
     {
         x.AddDelayedMessageScheduler();
         cfg.Host(builder.Configuration["AzureServiceBusConfiguration:ConnectionString"]);
         cfg.SetNamespaceSeparatorTo("_");

         cfg.ConfigureEndpoints(context);
         cfg.UseServiceBusMessageScheduler();
     });
 });

Consumer
public class OnArchiveTimedRequestsToCheaperStorage : IJobConsumer<ArchiveTimedRequestsToCheaperStorage>
{
    public async Task Run(JobContext<ArchiveTimedRequestsToCheaperStorage> context)
    {
        bool run = true;
        while (run)
        {
            await Task.Delay(2000);
        }
    }
}


public class OnArchiveTimedRequestsToCheaperStorageDefinition : ConsumerDefinition<OnArchiveTimedRequestsToCheaperStorage>
{
    protected override void ConfigureConsumer(IReceiveEndpointConfigurator endpointConfigurator
        , IConsumerConfigurator<OnArchiveTimedRequestsToCheaperStorage> consumerConfigurator
        , IRegistrationContext context)
    {
        consumerConfigurator.Options<JobOptions<ArchiveTimedRequestsToCheaperStorage>>(options => options
            .SetConcurrentJobLimit(1));
    }
}

Azure SB


You're submitting the jobs using the same JobId, or if you aren't using SubmitJob<T>, you're specifying the same RequestId property which is then used for the JobId.
Every job must have a unique identifier.

Boom. That was it. Thanks Chris. For whatever reason, I didn't realize in your sample that you were passing in a job object with a unique id and the actual message was in a separate property from within that job. I was just publishing my message itself with no identifier. Thanks so much.
